# On Demand data loading with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am creating graphic application and where the user can import the graphic data from a SQL Sever database. This application should be capable of handling at least 100,000+ entities. The idea to load the data faster is to load the visual data while opening the database file and non-visual data will be loaded on demand. So, the problem which I am facing is with the data loading from database using Entity Framework.

Each entity has a visual and a non-visual data associated and following is an example of one of the entity:

```
class Polyline
{
  Guid ID {get; set;}
  PolylineGeometry PGeometry {get; set;}
  PolylineAttribData PAttribData {get; set;}
}
class PolylineGeometry
{
  List<Point3D> PointCollection {get; set;}
}
class PolylineAttribData
{
  Image ImageData {get; set;}
}
```

My context class is as follows:

```
class GeometryData : DbContext
{
  DbSet<Polyline> Polylines {get; set;}
}
```

So, when we create the database context or the geometry data initially only the ID is loaded into polyline and PGeometry & PAttribData is not loaded. So, how do I load this data?

Thank You,

Pankaj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you must set Navigation Properties (refering to other entities) as virtual.

Then, wether you use lazy loading : the related entities will be loaded "on demand", as far as your context is not disposed.

Or you can load them explicitely when needed, using `Load()`

You can find a good article about lazy, eager, explicit loading, pros and cons here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh205756.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the solution is works fine. OK, I understand the concept behind different type of loading. I used Eager Loading to load the "PAttribData" data property on demand as GeometryData gD = new GeometryData(); 
var polyLinesWithGeometryAndAttributes = gD.Polylines.Include("PGeometry").Include("PAttribData");             Now, what if I want to unload the attribute data.

Comment: So, the idea behind this technique is that bring in the data on which user want to work and once the work is done, then unload it. This will help in maintaining the memory on RAM.

Comment: @Pankaj well your code is not that clear, missing a context somewhere. The idea is to load what you need when you need, lazily (which means X call to database) or eagerly (which means one big transfer from "database to object"). Each time your "action" is terminated, you dispose your context. When you dispose, nothing remains in memory.

Comment: Actually the context is created once for each project when loaded into the application. So, Initially after loading a project all the polylines will be displayed on the view control and when user clicks on any of the polyline its attribute data will be loaded (using eager or lazy loading technique) into a property window. When user unselect the polyline its attribute data should be unloaded. So, here I cannot dispose my context, it can only be disposed when the project is unloaded.

Answer (score 1):

you should explicitly write include statements;

```
GeometryData gD = new GeometryData();
var polyLinesWithGeometryAndAttributes = gD.Polylines.Include("PGeometry").Include("PAttribData");
```